# How to find an sentence inside of an array of words and join the words

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

Follow the example:

```js
const arrayOfSentences = ['fallen little short', 'hold the nominal office of governess', 'shadow of authority', 'the real evils indeed']
const arrayOfwords = ['who', 'had','fallen', 'little','short','of','a','mother','in','affection','hold','the','nominal','office','of','governess','the','mildness','of','her','temper','had','hardly','allowed','her','to','impose','any','restraint;','and','the','shadow','of','authority','being','now','long','passed','away,','they','had']
```

the output should be the array of words but with the sentences merged, for example ("fallen", "little", "short" -> "fallen little short"):

```js
const mergedArray = ['who', 'had','fallen little short','of','a','mother','in','affection','hold the nominal office of 
governess','the','mildness','of','her','temper','had','hardly','allowed','her','to','impose','any','restraint;','and','the','shadow of authority','being','now','long','passed','away,','they','had']
```

Comment: Don't understand why you need to join the words when you only can find the words in that order?

Comment: I guess you would have to split each sentence into words. Then search for the first word, if you find it check if the second word comes directly after that and so on...

Comment: @DennisVash the problem is: after that each word will be a clickable component on react... and this component should be words and sentences. that's why!

Comment: @Scorpioo590 yeah, I thought would be simple like that... but actually it is harder because I there are many sentences to search thru with same words for example "of"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a sneaky way to do that:

```js
const arrayOfSentences = ['fallen little short', 'hold the nominal office of governess', 'shadow of authority', 'the real evils indeed']
const arrayOfwords = ['who', 'had','fallen', 'little','short','of','a','mother','in','affection','hold','the','nominal','office','of','governess','the','mildness','of','her','temper','had','hardly','allowed','her','to','impose','any','restraint;','and','the','shadow','of','authority','being','now','long','passed','away,','they','had']

let sentence = arrayOfwords.join(' ');

arrayOfSentences.forEach(s => {
  sentence = sentence.replace(s, s.replace(/\s/g, '|'));
});

const mergedArray = sentence.split(' ').map(s => s.replace(/\|/g, ' '));

console.log(mergedArray);
```

Basically what it does is to make the whole `arrayOfwords` a sentence.

Then loop through the `arrayOfSentences` to find the appearances in that sentence and replace them to some placeholders.

Then re-split the sentence to an array, and replace the placeholders as what it was in `arrayOfSentences`.